# Where do I find files that I have chosen to "keep on Device" from Google Drive?

Tags: internal-storage, google-drive

I know that I can save a file to my device from Google Drive but I can't find where they are stored in the File Manager app.  Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the files after download in :

> Storage -> emulated -> 0 -> Download

or also for example just for Pictures after download,

***you can go to Gallery*** and then click on the picture and See `Details` of the picture you need to file path.

Comment: Thank you for that.  Do you know how I can download a folder or multiple files at one go?  Doing it individually is a pain.

Comment: hey `Alan`, Please ask this question with [ASK QUESTION](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)  on community.